# How can just apply forward propagation for single-layer-feed-forward or multi-layer-feed-forward models by Keras?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation

I was wondering if it is possible to implement **single-layer-feed-forward** and **multi-layer-feed-forward** models on time-series data just by using forward-propagation in Keras  to predict some features? Since Keras performs backpropagation implicitly with no need for a special command. As you know single-layer-feed-forward and multi-layer-feed-forward models are considered as feed-forward approach and as far as I know using `optimizer` in  back-propagation just by `model.compile(optimizer='adam')` they will allow us to bring the error functions to a minimum with low computational resources.

Moreover Is there any relationship between fully-connected models and backpropagation?
I would really welcome some Python code to explain so, if there is any for helping me to understand from implementation point of view in this simple concept from prediction-based usage of ANN by **Keras**.

I've shared datasets here for [train](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YgbhwIgnW42bwOnaxM2e_JHwsf3Q9O2_/view?usp=sharing) & [test](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yLvWbBp58TppW0q16_jy8F8xr7nvuM1A/view?usp=sharing).
Thanks for your attention and ask a naive question in this area!

Comment: I don't understand the question, please make it clearer, to me it sounds like you are asking if you can use FF neural network to model time series.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro that's right but by **Keras**

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment, if you are looking to model time series with feed-forward networks and iteratively feed the inputs, that is just the [SimpleRNN](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) which is "Fully-connected RNN where the output is to be fed back to input."

At each time step a feed-forward network is used and the recurrent aspect is just an unrolled version of chained feed-forward networks that **share the same weights**. It computes `tanh(Wx + b + Uh)` where `h` is the previous output, you can consider that a feed-forward network with 2 inputs, the current timestep input and the previous output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but regarding implementation single-layer FF & Multi-layer FF by **Keras** , I would really welcome some Python code to do so, if there is any.